how to add email sending port to the security group in AWS ec2 instance
I'm trying to send an email from my back end that is hosted on an ec2 instance on amazon web services , but the function that runs this part takes a very long time to start the request that it gives me back a timeout error , so i think i need to add the port in the security group but am not aware how to set this up !! here is how my email server settings looks like :
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my email here"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my password here"



Traditionally, security groups on EC2 instances are configured to "Allow All Outbound" because you can normally trust your own resources. Is that how your security group is configured? Is the instance in a Public Subnet or a Private Subnet?
